# Django form data is not saved into database

Tags: django, django-forms

When I submit my form, I get:

```
[21/Apr/2023 10:35:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 882
```

but the data is not saved into the database.

I think the issue is in Views.py:

```
@requires_csrf_token
def competitors(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CompetitorsReg(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       text = form.cleaned_data['Competitors']
       form.save()
  else:
    form = CompetitorsReg()
  return render(request, 'forms.html')
```

Models.py

```
class Competitors(models.Model):
  flname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Weight = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(50), MaxValueValidator(300)])
  rank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Registration form</h1>

<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
     {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="flname" name="flname">First and Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="flname" name="fname"><br>
    <label for="Weight" name="Weight">Weight:</label><br>
    <input type="interger" id="Weight" name="Weight"><br>
    <label for="rank" name="rank">Rank:</label><br>
    <select name="rank" id="rank>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <ul>
    {% for x in tourcompetitors %}
      <li>{{ competitors.flname }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul> 
  </html>
```

```
class CompetitorsReg(forms.ModelForm): name = forms.CharField(required=False) weight = forms.ImageField() rank = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Meta:
    model = Competitors
    fields = ["flname", "Weight", "rank",]
    labels = {'flname': "Full Name", "Weight": "Weight", 'rank': "rank",}
```

I can create and save information in the admin panel, but the information is not saved from the form. I don't receive any error message. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post the forms.html, urls.py and the form. Did you check if form.is_valid() returns True?

Comment: Hi, I added the html file. I am not sure how to check if form.is_valid() returns True.

Comment: just add a print inside the if clause to see if code is executed. How is competitorsReg defined?

Comment: It returns TRUE. I added competitorsReg.